# Get Mysql table column names in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to get the mysql table column names using a method like getColumnNames() in app script?

```
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://address/name", "username","password"); 
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bookings;"); 
  var result = stmt.executeQuery(); 
  var mat = [];
   mat[0] = [];

  mat.push(result.getColumnNames() );
```

getColumnNames() is not defind for Jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there any way to get the mysql table column names using a method like getColumnNames() in app script?**

There's actually a function named [getColumnName(column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-result-set-meta-data#getcolumnnamecolumn) from the `JdbcResultSetMetaData`. I think that's what you're looking for. 
Here's additional info from the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)) where it's derived from.

```
getColumnName

    String getColumnName(int column)
                         throws SQLException
    Get the designated column's name.
    Parameters:
    column - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...
    Returns:
    column name
    Throws:
    SQLException - if a database access error occurs
```